# No se puede importar opencv incluso si está instalado

Tags: python, windows10, opencv, cv2

Tengo un archivo donde importo `cv2`.
Sin embargo mientras que tengo `opencv-python` installado me devuelve el terminal :

```
(sum_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer>rodrigo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer\rodrigo.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Incluso lo desinstalé y lo reinstalé pero no funciona.

```
(sum_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer> pip uninstall opencv-python
Uninstalling opencv-python-3.4.3.18:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\projects\summarizer\sum_env\lib\site-packages\cv2\*
    c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\projects\summarizer\sum_env\lib\site-packages\opencv_python-3.4.3.18.dist-info\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled opencv-python-3.4.3.18
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(sum_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer>pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/50/04d0669afe884f137c2f490642756e8c4a658254300a9eaf253d1e643085/opencv_python-4.1.0.25-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (37.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 37.4MB 112kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\projects\summarizer\sum_env\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.15.4)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.1.0.25
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(sum_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer>rodrigo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer\rodrigo.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "c:/users/antoi/documents/programming/projects/summarizer/sum_env/lib/site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

He verificado que no hay un archivo que tiene el nombre `cv2.py` pero parece que no :

[image: resultado del busca de cv2.py]

Comment: Verifica que no tengas por ahi un script tuyo que se llame `cv2.py` que esté causando colisión con el instalado.

Comment: @abulafia Hice la investigación pero no me da nada. Busqué en el directorio raíz de todos mis proyectos de programación y actualicé la pregunta con una captura de pantalla..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto sucede cuando Python no puede encontrar el directorio de OpenCV.
intenta agregando esta linea en tu código:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
```

Si no resulta, intenta acceder [aquí](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) para obtener los binarios correspondientes, 
luego instalalos con

```
pip install "d:\opencv\opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
```